# how to upgrade firmware intel wifi iwlwifi ? unstable wireless Intel 7260 with lenovo t440p

Tags: wireless, 14.10, backport, iwlwifi

How to upgrade the  firmware intel WiFi  from 7260-10 to 7260-12.

on Intel page said: "Installation of the firmware is simply:"

```
# cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

So I have

```
#sudo ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-*
-rw-r----- 1 root root 672352 Mar 19 14:19 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 782300 Mar 19 13:35 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 683236 Nov 24 15:42 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 679780 Dec  1 15:16 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 680508 Dec  1 20:45 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
```

But I doesn't load the last version 7260-12, trying to reboot but no luck it stays with 7260-10 .

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.673076] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: found PCI INT A -> IRQ 10
[    4.673090] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: sharing IRQ 10 with 0000:00:1c.1
[    4.680093] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 23.15.10.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

and

```
modinfo iwlmvm 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-6-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v3.19-rc1-0-g97bf6af) using backports v3.19-rc1-1-0-g74aaf28
```

I have unstable WiFi connection.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode.bak
sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
```

Then reboot, renaming the file works sometimes

You could edit the source from the backports by going into the backports directory and into `/driver/net/wireless/iwlwifi` and edit `iwl-7000.c` line 72 as it should be

```
#define IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX   10
```

and change it to

```
#define IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX   12
```

Save and exit text editor, then you can

```
make clean
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

and see if it will load the `12.ucode` without changing file names.

Comment: thanks you, it loads the 7260-12 but the WiFi still unstable I think I need to downgrade to 7260-9 or 7260-8, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: You could do another edit of the source code to line 80 to change it from 9 to 8 and save and reinstall the backports.  Then check /lib/firmware and delete or rename the iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode, iwlwifi-7260-11.ucode, and iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode and see how it works with the iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode after a reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31: Hi!  Thanks for the answer. I encounter exactly the same problem as the OP, but the `iwl-7000.c` doesn't seem to appear on my system.  What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @SamBruns iwl-7000.c is a kernel source code file.  The [backports](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/07/31/) likely are already patched to use the 7260-12.ucode file

Comment: @Jeremy31: I would like to update them to use the `7260-12.ucode` file. So I guess that I'm supposed to recompile the source file and reinstall the backports, but I don't know how to do that. Could you redirect me to any explanation or give a short explanation, if possible?

Comment: Ask a new question so there is room for the answer.  Have you tried renaming the 12.ucode file to a lower number to see if it will load?

Comment: @Jeremy31: You're right.  I asked :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/677585/upgrading-iwlwifi-firmware-on-lenovo-t540p