# Upgrading iwlwifi 7260 firmware on Lenovo T540p

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, iwlwifi, firmware

Because of a really unstable Wifi connection, I think upgrading the firmware of my Intel(R) Wireless N 7260 from 7260-10 to 7260-14 could possibly fix the problem.

I stumbled upon [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600231/how-to-upgrade-firmware-intel-wifi-iwlwifi-unstable-wireless-intel-7260-with-l), where the top answerer wrote this:

> Have you tried
>
> ```
> sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode.bak
> sudo cp /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
> ```
>
> Then reboot, renaming the file works sometimes
>
> You could edit the source from the backports by going into the
>   backports directory and into `/driver/net/wireless/iwlwifi` and edit
>   `iwl-7000.c` line 72 as it should be
>
> ```
> #define IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX   10
> ```
>
> and change it to
>
> ```
> #define IWL7260_UCODE_API_MAX   12
> ```

I tried renaming the files as proposed, without success (after rebooting, `modinfo iwlwifi` and `dmesg` indicates that the version stays the same).

I would like to try the second option, so if I correctly understood, I have to recompile the `iwl-7000.c` source file as explained and reinstall the backports, but I really don't know how to do that. Also the `iwl-7000.c` source file is currently not present on my system.

Could anybody explain me how to do that?

Ps: My kernel's version is `3.19.0-28-generic`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: @Pilot6: Where exactly the firmware is being updated on the answer you provided on this post?

Comment: The firmware is not updated, but the problem with low quality connection is solved.

Comment: No it's not. I already know how to disable 802.11n mode, that's not my question :)

Comment: OK. I will give you the answer.

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -a`?

Comment: `3.19.0-28-generic`

Comment: It is already changed in 3.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution with the replacement of `iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode` with `iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode` is a "cheat" for the kernel.

The module  `iwl-7000.c` is searching for maximum version `iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode` and loads it. When you replace the file it loads the new firmware.

In this case you do not need to edit the kernel source. If that solution does not improve your wireless connection, then the firmware update does not help.

The second "option" is not an option. It is the patch to `iwl-7000.c` to get it search for `iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode` instead of `iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode`. That will not improve anything, it will just load the original firmware file without renaming.

You will not find kernel source in your system. To patch the source you will need to download the kernel source, patch it, and then compile the kernel or just `iwlwifi` module.

You can find a lot of [guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) how to compile Linux kernel in the net or even some specific kernel modules. But it is not worth studying in this  case, because the first "option" does the same for you.

In addition, in kernel 3.19 that patch **is already there**, so you do not need to rename the file. That is why it does not work.

See [iwl-7000.c](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-vivid.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-7000.c) in Ubuntu kernel 3.19.

**Just leave the original iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode file name.**

**P.S.** You found an old solution. Now the latest firmware is already `iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode` and it is available in Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 already. But still there are issues with this wireless adapter.

So I suggest using the workaround.

**P.P.S** You can try to replace `iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode` with `iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` the 3.19 kernel tries to load the version `12`, but `14` may have some improvements or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wanted to upgrade to 7260-14 and I didn't see that this patch was already there.

Comment: @SamBruns You can replace `iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode` with `iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` and test it. IT MAY WORK.

Comment: I see. So upgrading will not help in my case.. Anyway for educational purposes, could you redirect me to some material explaining how to recompile a module? I did some search on Google but I'm quite lost because of the abundance of results :p

Comment: The kernel searches for `12` now. If you cheat it with `14` it may be improved.

Comment: Look for kernel compile https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: I'll try renaming the file then. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Rename 14 to 12 and put it to `/lib/firmware`. And report if this helps.

Comment: I renamed.  `dmesg | grep iwl` says `[    4.686647] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.17.12.0 op_mode`. I suppose this is ok?

Comment: It looks that it has been loaded. Now test how it works.

Comment: It seems to be great :)

Comment: Really? Then please write an answer with the description of what you did. I will improve it, if needed and award a bounty for you. @SamBruns Please give a link to the firmware you've downloaded, etc.

Comment: Ok. :) First I will let it run for some time to see how it behaves.

Comment: @SamBruns: how log is "some time"?  People want to reward you for your work!