# Ubuntu 15.04 kernel 3.19+ Intel Wireless AC-7260

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, intel-wireless

I'm using the ubuntu 15.04 (kernel 3.19+) but the driver that I'm using it's not working well.
Comparing it with widowns I'm losing ~50% of signal.

I'm comming from linux mint that also wasn't able to use the correct driver or configuration.
I already tried change kernel version and install the drivers in this list:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi#Firmware
The last one that I tried was:
3.19+   iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.17.12.0.tgz

Any suggestions of how to fix it it's very wellcome
thanks

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/677585/upgrading-iwlwifi-7260-firmware-on-lenovo-t540p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

There is no other driver than the one provided by Intel for this wireless card.

However sometimes connection issues can be resolved by:

- unplugging your computer from the power line (just power off will not be sufficient) to reset the device.
- unplugging the antennas cables from the card, and re-plugging in a changed order

[image]

Comment: I already try disconnect/connect, unfortunately this is not the solution.
As I said the signal on Windows10 is perfect 100%

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @LeonardoMascarenhas: sad to hear... on my box this very adapter works as expected most of the time. But it needs a complete disconnect from mains from time to time.